# How to avoid multiple "of-phrase" in a sentence?

Tags: redundancy

I am writing a scientific article, Please suggest me an alternative to sentence below to avoid "of" phrase multiple times.

> The polarization and rotation angle **of** BO6 octahedron **of** some
>   perovskite materials are listed in table

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid them? Also, you need an article before BO6.

Comment: @Catija thank you. It looked little awkward to me to have two of-phrase so close in one sentence.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Not applicable, due to the scientific nature of the example.

Comment: @user2958481  "Please suggest ***to*** me an alternative..."

Comment: @CathyGartaganis How does the scientific nature exempt it from being a dupe?

Comment: @Catija If you read the link, you'll see that the sentence structure suggested is different from the one I provided, due to the scientific nature of the example.

Answer (score 1):

The BO6 octahedron polarization and rotation angle of selected perovskite materials are listed in the table.

Comment: @user2958481  You're welcome.